How can I detect whether my file path is inside a google drive folder or not using C#?
I have a windows desktop C# application, that saves some data using a customized file format.
I want to stop the user from saving such files at the google drive location as during sync usually these files get corrupted.
So my question is how can I detect that the saving path entered by the user is a google drive path. Note that my application is an offline one , I don't think I'll be able to use any Google drive API .. all the checks must run without internet connection
I tried using the solution at How do I programmatically locate my Google Drive folder using C#? but it is always failing as I couldn't find the sync_config.db file in the suggested path.
